# CakePHP Access a different table my view

Tags: cakephp

I have two tables Contact and Quote, this is a one to many relationship (i.e. one contact can have many quotes). Foreign keys are all setup correctly.

When I go to create a new quote I want to be able to select from a drop down list of contacts.

My code looks like this:

Contact Model:

```
class Contact extends AppModel {        
    public $hasMany = array('Quote' => array('className' => 'Quote', 'foreignKey' => 'contact_id'));
}
```

Quote Model

```
class Quote extends AppModel {      
    public $belongsTo = array('Contact' => array('className' => 'Contact', 'foreignKey' => 'contact_id'));

    public $validate = array(
            'name' => array(
                    'rule' => 'notEmpty'
            ),
            'amount' => array(
                    'rule' => 'notEmpty'
            )
    );      
}
```

Add method in QuotesController:

```
public function add() {
    // TODO: Update this so the user can select the id from a drop down list.  
    $this->request->data['Quote']['contact_id'] = '1';

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {                   
        $this->Quote->create(); // This line writes the details to the database.
        if ($this->Quote->save($this->request->data)) {             
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your quote has been saved.');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {                
            $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to add your quote.');
        }            
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm currently just hard coding the user id as part of the add process.

Comment: Stephen, will you clarify your goal? What do you expect to happen, what is currently happening, and what problems have you encountered that prevent you from accomplishing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have read and are using this method in your view.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::select

Less easy to find (or easier to overlook) is this:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list

So in your controller you want to do

```
$contacts = $this->Article->find('list', array('fields' => array('Contact.id', 'Contact.name'));
$this->set(compact('contacts'));
```

Then in the view:

```
echo $this->Form->select('contact_id', $contacts);
```

Modify the fields for the find to reflect what is actually in your model. And if you need fields combined, you can possibly do it with virtual fields: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html. Otherwise you can select the fields that need to be composited and use a foreach loop to combine them into a id=>[displayed value] array to pass on to the view. Only the id is the important thing and has to correspond to an id in the Contacts table.

Comment: Actually, if everything is [set up right](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#creating-form-elements), you don't even need the `$contacts` in the form echo (`$this->Form->select('contact_id', $contacts)`), with a simple `$this->Form->input('contact_id')` the select will be well formed.

Comment: @Erik, I made those changes but I'm getting the following error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Comment: I think is error might have something to do with my model associations, I'll have to investigate further.

Comment: I'm still having trouble with this, as far as I can tell my model associations are setup correctly.

Comment: @Stephen Are you getting the list with `$this->Quote->Contact->find('list' /*etc*/)` inside your QuotesController? Otherwise post the `find` function you're executing to help you solve the "find() on a non-object" error.

Comment: @Nunser Thanks very much, that fixed. My drop down box now has all my contacts in it.